# wordpress upload_error Unable to create directory

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

Trying to upload image files at Media Library, and when I upload a file I get following error

> “306.gif” has failed to upload due to an error
>   Unable to create directory uploads/2014/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

the permissions for wp-content and wp-content/uploads are already `0777`

and I have also tried by changing the ownership for my project directory `www-data`

```
chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress1
```

I think it starts occurring from yesterday when I updated the wordpress to 3.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in wp-admin > Settings > Media, the location for file upload in the field `Store uploads in this folder` wasn't correct it supposed to be an absolute path to my app > wp-content > uploads

```
/var/www/app.dev/wp-content/uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

Please

1. login with FTP
2. Go to your upload folder
3. Press right button of your mouse
4. Change you permission to 777 all

it must work now.